# App Engine Terminates Active Instance Unexpectedly Upon Reaching idle_timeout Limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am currently facing an issue where my instance, with basic_scaling and an idle_timeout set to the maximum limit of 60 minutes, is being terminated while processing a request if the time since the last request reaches one hour.

The documentation says that for basic scaling:

> 24 hours for HTTP requests and task queue tasks. If your app doesn't return a request within this time limit, App Engine interrupts the request handler and emits an error for your code to handle.
> A basic-scaled instance can choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many hours without returning an HTTP response code.

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs16
env: standard
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 60m
```

Can anyone please help on this?

I tried increasing the idle_time but its maximum value is 60m.